# here filtering terminate TLS in openvpn but not ssl

Tags: ssl, openvpn, tls

I have configured an openvpn sever appliance on vmware and windows 2008 R2 and set it to use port 80 for openvpn, iphone and ipad could connect to it but windows and mac could't and generated error in TLS handshaking , I know iph.. and ipad use ssl instead of TLS then I think here in Iran they can terminate TLS authentication in some way , is there any way to solve it?